# Can t get a text as value in select tag

Tags: php, html

I have a select drop down where I want in the value the text from db. If I have a value like "word1 word2" I get in post only first word. How can I do to have all text?

```
<div class="form-group">
 <label>Functie</label>
 <select name="functie" id="functie" class="form-control">
 <option value="">&nbsp;</option>
<?php 
$stmt = $connection->query("SELECT * from functii order by functie ASC");
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
echo "<option value=$row[functie]>$row[functie]</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
?>
 </select>
</div>
```

So basically $row[functie] can have as value 1,2 or three words....and in my case I get only first one if i select one of these

Thank you

Comment: You close the "<select>" on line 9 so the select will end after only one loop.

Comment: You are right, I have to select close but is not related to my issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change how you are building your `option` lines in the loop. The value needs to be enclosed in quotes. Change:

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo "<option value=$row[functie]>$row[functie]</option>";
}
```

to

```
while ($row = $stmt->fetch_assoc()) {
    echo '<option value="' . $row[functie] . '">' . $row[functie] . '</option>';
}
```

Comment: thanks    echo "<option value = '".$row[functie]."' >$row[functie]</option>";   did the trick